# url of webpage in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, url, servlets

I just need little help, that is: many times i have seen `http://www.xyz.com/index.jsp?etetet%rr^_frfwrw....`. I just wanted to know that what is this question mark `?etetet%....`coming after `index.jsp` and why this is coming after index.jsp? Can somebody please explain what is the reason behind this?

I am also running my application like this: http://localhost:8080/myproject/index.jsp

How can i make my url to be looked like the above one i.e. `http://localhost:8080/myproject/index.jsp?..eeqwe_%cdc...`

I am using jsp, servlet and tomcat server.Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hum... Have you ever heard of URL query strings? If not, have a look [there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

Comment: @sp00m ok i saw it but can you please tell me what is the reason behind this query parameter? Why this is coming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is called URL query, or URL parameters. These parameters are accessible in your HttpRequest object like this:

```
String name = (String) request.getParameter("name");
```

For a URL like `blah?name=Donkey`, the String variable `name` will receive a 'Donkey'.

Unlike your example, the parameters commonly come as key-value pairs, ie. = and when more than one parameter is passed, the pairs are divided by ampersands:

`blah?name=Donkey&quantity=10`

Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: ok but how parameters are sent in encrypted format and what is the reason behind this?

Comment: Reason behind encryption is typically a sensitive nature of the information being transmitted. The encrypted parameters may be passed the same way as the non-encrypted ones, as far as the HTTP specification is concerned - the actual data doesn't really matter. An important thing is for the receiving party to be able to decrypt the data.

Answer (score 2):

This is called in java a "query string"
All elements passed after the ? character can be retrieve from request.getQueryString()

for example

```
test.jsp?myparam
```

the call to request.getQueryString() will return you "myparam"

Normally, you pass some parameters using key=value pattern separating by & character in order to use a parser to understand several parameters
for example

```
test.jsp?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

Be carefull, the length of the URL is limited to 255 characters